# How to trigger a multiple run in a single pipeline job of jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job which run with below pipeline groovy script,

```
pipeline {
     parameters{
    string(name: 'Unique_Number', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter Unique Number')
        }  
    stages {
            stage('Build') {
            agent { node {  label 'Build'  } }
            steps {
               script {
               sh build.sh
                    }
                }

            stage('Deploy') {
            agent { node {  label 'Deploy'  } }
            steps {
               script {
               sh deploy.sh
                    }
                }

            stage('Test') {
            agent { node {  label 'Test'  } }
            steps {
               script {
               sh test.sh
                    }
                }

           }
         }
```

I just trigger this job **multiple times** with different **unique ID number** as input parameter. So as a result i will have multiple run/build for this job at different stages.

With this, i need to trigger a multiple run/build to be promote to next stage (i.e., from build to deploy or from deploy to test) in this pipeline job as a **one single build** instead of triggering each and every single run/build to next stage. Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 2):

I was also trying to do the same thing and found no relevant answers. May this help to someone.

This will read a file that contains the Jenkins Job name and run them iteratively from one single job.

Please change below code accordingly in your Jenkins.

```html
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
             script{
            git branch: 'Your Branch name', credentialsId: 'Your crendiatails', url: ' Your BitBucket Repo URL '

##To read file from workspace which will contain the Jenkins Job Name ###
           
     def filePath = readFile "${WORKSPACE}/ Your File Location"                   

##To read file line by line ###
 
     def lines = filePath.readLines() 
      
##To iterate and run Jenkins Jobs one by one ####

                    for (line in lines) {                                            
                      build(job: "$line/branchName",
                        parameters:
                        [string(name: 'vertical', value: "${params.vertical}"),
                        string(name: 'environment', value: "${params.environment}"),
                        string(name: 'branch', value: "${params.aerdevops_branch}"),
                        string(name: 'project', value: "${params.host_project}")
                        ]
                    )
                        }  
                                       }
                    
         }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start multiple jobs from one pipeline if you run something as:

```
build job:"One", wait: false
build job:"Two", wait: false
```

Your main job starts children pipelines and children pipelines will run in parallel.

You can read [PipeLine Build Step documentation for more information](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#-build-%20build%20a%20job).

Also, you can read about the [parallel run in declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)

[Here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/) you can find a lot of examples for parallel running