# How to define triggers for multiple repo mapped to single pipeline?

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Build process demands to checkout the code from multiple repository, in below groovy scripting

```
checkout('repo1', branchName)
checkout('repo2',branchName)
```

before building the code, in a single pipeline.

---

How to define the trigger for multiple repositories in a single pipeline(scripted)?

1) in the case to trigger for every new commit

2) in the case to trigger for specific tag

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple repositories which should trigger Jenkins builds, the respective repositories need to have Jenkinsfiles in place.

The key is that every repository should call a JenkinsSharedLibrary, which gives you the possibility to maintain your jenkins builds in one central source, instead of having multiple "hardcoded" jenkinsfiles per repository.

This article describes the use case of a shared library and how to use Jenkins across multiple git repos.

https://bjurr.com/managing-1000-repos-in-jenkins-with-a-breeze/

Comment: Do you want me to copy the same Jenkinsfile in every repo??

Comment: My Jenkins file, checkout source code from multiple repo and build it

Answer (score 0):

Create two pipelines each one build individual repo.

Then create the third pipeline for trigger build of two previous pipelines. You can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907965/1573395) in another thread how to do this.

After this in each of repos create webhook that trigger the build of the third pipeline. [Here](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline) good tutorial on how to do this.

All above together allows to you approach the simplest solution for your problem.

Comment: there are 8 repos

Comment: Yes this is simple solution

Comment: There are 8 repos, if 4th repo triggers the main pipeline, which job should be triggered?

Comment: Why this is a problem?

Comment: Can you invite me to private chatroom? I wanna discuss on this for 5 mins

Comment: one pipeline have webhook -> trigger 8 another pipelines

Comment: If only 4th repository(say) out of 8 repos has latest commit, then pipeline(having webhook) should trigger only one pipeline(4th) but not all 8

Comment: Big problem is each job has its own workspace per repo

Comment: You any way clone all repos to disk. All together or in separate pipelines take the same size on disk. The pipeline workspace is very small size usually this is just directory